# What is correct way to change image src using variable on different page?

Tags: javascript

javaScript Code:

```
function Productadd() {
    var imageid = document.getElementById("pic1").src;
    var textid = document.getElementById("text1").textContent;
    localStorage.setItem("imagesrc", imageid);
    localStorage.setItem("text", textid);
    window.location.href = "E:/GOO%20WEB/medic-care/index3.html";
    imageid = imageid.toString();
    textid = textid.toString();
    document.getElementById("image2").src = localStorage.getItem("imagesrc");
    document.getElementById("text2").textContent = localStorage.getItem("textid");
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: You can not change an image on the next page that is loaded from the current page. The code only executes on the current page. So what you want to do is not possible. You would need to have code running on the next page and trigger it somehow with localstorage, cookie, or a querystring parameter.

Comment: Tacking on to @epascarello's insightful comment - would you consider it useful if any page you visited could modify the look/feel/function of any subsequent page it *might* redirect you to? This would open massive security holes (phishing) and opportunities for awful UX.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change an image on the next page that is loaded from the current page. The code only executes on the current page. So what you want to do is not possible.

You would need to have code running on the next page and trigger it somehow with localstorage, cookie, or a querystring parameter.